# Understanding F# type constructors

Tags: .net, syntax, f#, constructor

I am trying to create a complex type and need, at construction time, to perform some actions.
So I started writing my code:

```
type public MyType =
   val private myvar: int
   val private myvar2: string
   (* ...Some val declarations... *)
   new () = {
      (* The default ctor makes something *)
   }
   new (ctorpar: AnotherType) = {
      myvar = 1;
      myvar2 = "Hello";
      (* Other assignments in the form var = val *)
      (* Here I would like to start a cycle in order *)
      for i in ctorpar.array do
         (* Do something *) (* ERROR *)
   }
```

Well when trying to place a for or something else from an assignment the compiler goes mad.
I assume the following: The syntax for new follows the one of Computational Expressions, or better, the new is a computational expression (I imply this because of the curly brackets and the semicolon from one oinstruction to another one). And in this case, for constructor computetional expressions, it is possible to palce assignments only.

So please could you answer me:

1) Is my deduction correct? (regarding computetional expressions and the constructor for types).

2) What should I do whether I need to place an articulated set of instructions to be executed in the constructor???? Well you know, sometimes it is necessary to perform an action at construction time and it might involve everything from a cycle to all possibilities.

But the compiler gets mad anyway...

Thanks to kvd I understood that I have the possibility to do the following:

```
type public MyType =
   val private myvar: int
   val private myvar2: string
   (* ...Some val declarations... *)
   new () = {
      (* The default ctor makes something *)
   }
   new (ctorpar: AnotherType) = 
      for i in ctorpar.ACollection do
         (* Something *)
      {
      myvar = 1;
      myvar2 = "Hello";
      }
```

Well I am sorry, but this does not help me because F# compiler tells me this:

> Object constructors cannot directly
>   use try/with and try/finally prior to
>   the initialization of the object. This
>   includes constructors such as 'for x
>   in ...' that may elaborate to uses of
>   these constructs. This is a limitation
>   imposed by Common IL.

OK, if the problem is doing something prior to the object initalization, and it sounds correct, then let's do this after:

```
type public MyType =
   val mutable private myvar: int
   val mutable private myvar2: string
   (* ...Some val declarations... *)
   new () = {
      (* The default ctor makes something *)
   }
   new (ctorpar: AnotherType) = 
      {
      myvar = 1;
      myvar2 = "Hello";
      }
      then
      for i in ctorpar.ACollection do
         (* Something *)
         myvar <- 10
```

Again frustrated by failure:

> The value or constructor 'myvar' is
>   not defined.

What should I do????
It seems that after, it does not recognize elements in my class, it seems correct because it would require an indentifier as for when declaring members using self or this... here it does not have a self-reference and, correctly, tells me: "You're trying to get something I cannot give you!!!!!!"

Answer (score 16):

1. No, your inference is not correct.  The curly braces are more like a record construction expression, which can only contain field assignments.  *You cannot do anything other than assign values to each field within the braces.*
2. You can put statements before the field assignments (that is, before the opening brace) as normal.  If you then wish to execute other statements afterward, you need to use the `then` keyword:

   ```
   type public MyType =
     val private myvar: int
     val private myvar2: string

     new () = 
       for i in 1 .. 10 do
         printfn "Before field assignments %i" i
       { myvar = 1; myvar2 = "test" } 
       then 
         for i in 1 .. 10 do
           printfn "After field assignments %i" i
   ```

**Edit**

Regarding your new question, you can use `new (ctorpar:AnotherType) as this = ...` and then `this.myvar <- 10`.

Comment: kvb thank you very much you really clarify me everything, not only what I just asked, but even more. NOW IT MAKES SENSE. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where does the "then" keyword appear in the documentation? It definitely works, but I don't think I've seen it anywhere before.

Comment: @Ramon - see the "Executing Side Effects in Constructors" section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx.

Comment: @Andry - see my edit.  This is covered by the "Self Identifiers in Constructors" section of the MSDN page I previously linked to.

Answer (score 12):

The answer from kvb is great and gives you all the information you asked for :-).

I would just like to recommend to use the implicit syntax where primary constructor is written immediately following the name of the type. This makes so many things a lot easier:

```
type MyType(n:int, s:string) =
  do 
    // Run before fields initialized (they aren't accessible here)
    for i in 1 .. 10 do
      printfn "Before field assignments %i" i
  // Initialize fields (accessible from now on)
  let myvar = n
  let myvar2 = s
  do // Run after fields initialized - you can use them here
     for i in 1 .. 10 do
       printfn "After field assignments %i" i

  // You can add multiple constructors too:
  new() = MyType(0, "hi")
  member x.Foo = 0
```

Comment: Indeed, see also http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/the-basic-syntax-of-f-classes-interfaces-and-members/

Comment: Tomas Petricek and @kvb as usual, you two are a great help with all things F#.